# Ethernet Controller (Realtek r8125) not working with Kernel 5.15

Tags: networking, drivers, upgrade, ethernet, realtek

I have a homeserver on which I ran Ubuntu 20.04 till today. The ASRock H570 motherboard has a Realtek Dragon RTL8125BG controller (aka r8125). With 20.04 I managed to get the controller running with dkms and the help of [ubuntuusers](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Howto/Realtek-r8125/). The guide worked until kernel 5.4.0-113 then I got stuck.

My plan was to wait until I can upgrade to 22.04 because it has the kernel version 5.15 which according to internet sources (and the page indicated above) is supposed to support the controller "natively".

So today I did a `do-release-upgrade`. But still the it does not work. Does anyone have an idea why or can help track down the issue?

Note: The update went through until it asked me about the removal of old packages. I hit `d` for details. My muscle memory afterward did not hit `q` to exit but aborted the upgrade with `ctrl+c`. Aaaaaaahhrg. To make sure the system would boot I did a `grub-update`. The system boots. I can connect a USB-Ethernet-Adapter to access the internet yet only with USB2.0 ports (USB3.0 do not seem to work for the adapter). A `apt update && upgrade` did not detect anything that would be amiss. So hence my question above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thx

Comment: Please try: `sudo apt update` and then: `sudo apt install r8125-dkms` and reboot. Any improvement? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: whohooooo!! THANK YOU! This was the solution!
As I saw: dkms was set up. Can you confirm that the driver will be incorporated in future kernel updates automatically?

Comment: The purpose of the dkms process is to rebuild and reinstall the driver whenever Update Manager installs a new kernel version. It should work perfectly. I shall propose an answer that I hope you will accept: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The required *r8125-dkms* package is present in official Ubuntu repositories. I suggest:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install r8125-dkms
```

Several dependencies will also be installed.

Additionally, given that Ubuntu's default driver is the r8169, you also need to blacklist that driver:

```
sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-r8169.conf > /dev/null <<EOT
# To use r8125 driver explicitly
blacklist r8169
EOT

# apply the blacklisted driver
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot. You should be all set.